# mainactivity.java changed to a folder containing AppErrorResult

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am an Android beginner and I was working on my first project, which is a calculator for fractions. The app had an error which I was unable to fix and so I got frustrated and I quit (I didn't delete or do anything with the files tho). Around 3-4 days later (today) I suddenly got the solution. I opened up Android Studio, just to see that my mainactivity's icon is changed and it has become a kind of folder, which contains the file AppErrorResult. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's AppErrorResult:

```
package com.android.server.am;

final class AppErrorResult {
    public void set(int res) {
        synchronized (this) {
            mHasResult = true;
            mResult = res;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public int get() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (!mHasResult) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return mResult;
    }

    boolean mHasResult = false;
    int mResult;
}
```

Comment: When you double click on MainActivity, does it open a file, or does it just open like a folder? Right now, it looks like you accidentally dragged AppErrorResult from its library into your project.

Comment: @MarsAtomic  It just expands like a folder to show AppErrorResult inside. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to clean your project. Open the Build menu and select Clean. Let AS do its work and then rebuild the project using Build > Rebuild. I don't know for sure if this will work, but what you're seeing is definitely strange. If worse comes to worst, you can restore your project from backup. You do keep backups, don't you?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Wellllll no....I'll definitely keep backups from now on. Cleaning, rebuilding or invalidate cache/restart are not working. Is there any way I can restore a previous version?

Comment: Try opening the main activity file directly with a text editor. Beyond that, I don't know. You'd be best served by finding an Android Studio specific forum or check their bugbase for similar issues.